# Unable to run application while build app in react native android (Error : Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.)

Tags: android, react-native

Unable to run app on react native for development , build failed on execution 91% and showing below error attached in screenshot and also attached android/build.gradle.

[image: Error Screenshot]
[image: android/build.gradle]

Answer (score 0):

The dependency file might be corrupted, delete the cache under the below directory and build again. Then gradle will pull deleted dependency again from maven repository.

c:\Users\saqib.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\7935...